# Guest login can't see thankyou page

Tags: php, woocommerce, checkout

I have made some changes in the theme and I forced the checkout to pass through the login page. where you can find a guest login page which simply pass ?guest to URL.
My problem now is after finish the checkout, the guest is redirected to the login page. I know my problem is in functions.php but I don't know how to fix it.

functions.php

```
function wpk_checkout_user_logged() {
    if(function_exists('is_checkout') && is_checkout() && !is_user_logged_in() && !isset($_GET['guest'])  ) {

        $account_page_id = wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' );
        if($account_page_id == -1) {
            return;
        }

        $account_page_url = get_permalink( $account_page_id ) . '?checkout_redirect';
        wp_redirect($account_page_url);
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'wpk_checkout_user_logged');
```

Comment: So you are sending the guest user, that does not have an account, to the “my account” page – and now you are wondering why that asks for them to login first …?

Comment: every user is redirected to the login page. then if guest, just click guest. That's the scenario made by the previous developer. Is there any workaround ?

Comment: You are redirecting to the My Account page with the code shown above, and that simply makes little sense, if you don’t have a properly logged-in user - of course this redirects them to the login page first then. So you would need to fix this redirect, so that it goes elsewhere - somewhere that does not require login.